# How to replace values in a matrix based on specific indices?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, indexing

I'm trying to index a matrix based on an array of coordinates, so that I can replace the values in those positions with 1, and leave the rest as is. Here's what I mean:

I have the following 3x3 matrix

```
matrix = np.zeros((3,3), dtype=int)
matrix

>>> array([[0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0]])
```

and I have the following array

```
coords = np.array([[0,0],[2,1],[0,2]])
coords

>>> array([[0, 0],
           [2, 1],
           [0, 2]])
```

What I would like to do is replace the values in the original matrix with 1 only in the positions specified by the elements in the array `coords`. This is the desired output:

```
>>> array([[1, 0, 1],
           [0, 0, 0],
           [0, 1, 0]])
```

What I've tried to do is

```
matrix[coords]=1
```

However, this is the output I get:

```
>>> array([[1, 1, 1],
           [1, 1, 1],
           [1, 1, 1]])
```

Does anyone know how I can replace only the values in the positions specified, and obtain my desired output instead?

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: The layout of `coords` is not correct. Try with `matrix[coords[:,0], coords[:,1]] = 1`.

Comment: When given an array, indexing applies it to just one dimension.  A tuple is applied across dimensions.  `arr[x,y]` is the same as `arr[(x,y)]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run e.g.:

```
matrix[tuple(coords.T)] = 1
```